# Approval in Power Automate versus in Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapps

I am working on building an approval system which contain those main steps:-

1. Creator create a new SharePoint item using power app forms >> and email will be sent to first level approval.
2. the first level approval click on the link inside the email >> using power apps deep linking i will navigate the first level approver to the related item.
3. first level approval will have the option to Approver or Reject the form, using power app action buttons:-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1701254099428.png]

4. then once first approval approve, it will be sent to second approver , if rejected it will be sent to the creator and so on.
5. i have a power automate workflow to set the permission as the item moves through the process.

so i have implemented the actual approval using power apps and used power automate to send emails only. so is this a valid approach? or it is better for me to use power automate for doing the approval through these built-in actions:-

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1701254278949.png]

I chose power apps for these reasons:-

1. the approver can modify the form before approving or rejecting it, and can add comments.
2. approvers need to see all the data for him/her to take the approval decision, for example second approval, need to see the creator info, the first approval decision comments and approval history to take his/her decision.
3. also from a user perspective they feel it is easier to do the modification, read the previous data and do the approval action from the same screen, unlike when using power automate, where they will have to do the approval directly from their emails or from power automate , while read the data inside power app.. so they might find it difficulty to track which approval is for which item.

where archiving the above points using power automate will not be possible or will be difficult, so using power apps gave me more control over the approval process and provide an ease of use for the users .. so not sure if i am doing things correctly? or i should consider using power automate for the approval?

any advices and thoughts on this ?

thanks

Comment: The only point that rules out Power Automate for your scenario is the approvers modifying the form. Otherwise Power Automate is preferable, since the approvals are completely independent from the items. You can completely eliminate the need to give access to people to SharePoint and PowerApps. The approval emails sent by Power Automate are infinitely customizable with item details/change history.

Comment: @mmikesy90 changes to customer requirements need end, so i found using power apps for approval will be more flexible and adopt more to future chnages